# CSS and JS files not loaded in Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

Hello everyone I'm new to laravel I just finished my first app when I try to publish it in wamp the css and js files are not loaded,

I use

```
{{URL::to('/assets/css/main.css')}}
```

to call them, they are in the public folder and they are correctly loaded in PhpStorm, the path generated is

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/assets/css/main.css
```

and it's not correct, when I add `public` it works

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/public/assets/css/main.css
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use this to load your files:
`{{ asset('assets/css/main.css') }}`

If it doesn't work, that means you have a problem with your WAMP config, but nothing to do with Laravel itself.

Comment: The problem is related to WAMP. I'll try to help: Can you try, in your console, to go in your public folder, (`cd MyApp\public`) and from there, you do `php -S localhost:8000`. Then you load `localhost:8000` in your browser.

Comment: Is your site working from `localhost:8000` now? Because if it does, `http://localhost:8080/assets/css/main.css` should work, since `localhost:8000` == your public folder.

Comment: Yes it's but i still have the same problem

Comment: i renamed the file server.php to index.php and copied the .htaccess file from public to my folder app root folder. this link http://localhost:8080/assets/css/main.css dosn't work but this one works perfectly http://localhost:8000/public/assets/css/main.css